# how to randomize results from two querysets in django template

Tags: python, django

Friends, I want to know how we can present results from two different querysets in django template.

My views.py is as follows:

```
def index(request):
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request,"welcome/index.html",locals())
```

and My template is :

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {% for q in questions %}
        {{ q.title }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for a in answers %}
        {{ a.answer }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But as expected, this lists out the questions first and then answers. I would like to have randomly displayed questions and answers. Answers and Questions may come in any order in template. How do I do this, friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function?

```
import random

def index(request):
    answers = Answer.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    questions = Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    mixed = list(answers) + list(questions)
    random.shuffle(mixed)

    return render(request,"welcome/index.html",locals())
```

Now, you have a `mixed` list that is… mixed. You can loop over it. And you may check its type in the template, using:

```
{% for item in mixed %}
    {% if item.answer %}
        {{ item.answer }}
    {% else %}
        {{ item.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

(Just make sure the questions do not have an `answer` field)

Comment: That's what I'd do. You don't even need the if block. `{{ item.answer }}{{ item.title }}` will render the one that exists and an empty string for the other ;-)

Comment: I assumed he had more complex rendering for each, which he trimmed for the question. If not, your approach definitely works.

Comment: True, of course, and cleaner. I thought of it as a little trick worth knowing.

Comment: Thanks a lot friends. Actually I hadn't used shuffle function before. But your solution worked.Thanks again.